# Post an Ehepaar, wenn Frau einen Doppelnamen hat

Tags: letter

Wie adressiere ich richtig einen Brief an ein Ehepaar namens:

*Otto Mustermann, Erika Schmidt-Mustermann*?

Insbesondere:

- Muss / sollte die Frau oder der Mann zuerst genannt werden?
- Muss ich den Doppelnamen der Frau immer ausschreiben? Reicht vielleicht "Otto und Erika Mustermann?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bei der Anschrift werden die beiden Namen vollständig ausgeschrieben. Bei der Anrede lässt man für gewöhnlich den Vornamen weg.

> An Erika Schmidt-Mustermann und Otto Mustermann
>   Sehr geehrte Frau Schmidt-Mustermann, sehr geehrter Herr Mustermann

Siehe dazu auch: [Die richtige Anschrift für (Ehe-)Paare: So ist es heute richtig](http://www.sekada-daily.de/aktuelles/tipp/die-richtige-anschrift-f-r-ehe-paare-so-ist-es-heute-richtig.html).

Comment: Danke für die kurze und bündige Antwort und die Referenz.

Comment: "Ladies first" - other than that, the order is irrelevant

Answer (score 2):

In der Schweiz gibt's per Gesetz keine Doppelnamen mehr. Damit müsste ich immer beide Namen erwähnen. Aber schon vorher habe ich immer den Familiennamen desjenigen verwandt, den ich primär anschreibe. Wenn der Brief also v.a. an Otto gerichtet ist, weil er z.B. Ansprechpartner am Telefon gewesen war:

```
O. und E. Mustermann
Strasse Nr
PLZ Ort (ggf. Bundesland/Kanton)
```

Falls ich v.a. mit der Frau zu tun hatte, schreibe ich sie direkt an:

```
E. Schmidt
Strasse Nr
PLZ Ort
```

Ich empfehle sehr, "Hr."/"Fr."/"Fam." sowie ein vorangestelltes "An"/"an" wegzulassen. Es ist hinsichtlich Höflichkeit nicht mehr verlangt und verwirrt schlimmstenfalls die automatischen Sortieranlagen, wenn man es nicht schön geschrieben hat.

Wenn du beide anschreibst, empfehle ich die "traditionelle" Herangehensweise: Verwende den Namen des Mannes. Du kannst das natürlich auch umgekehrt halten, aber es ist trotz aller Gleichstellungsbemühungen heute immer noch häufig so, dass die Frau zum Mann zieht, d.h. die Post hat höchstwahrscheinlich seinen Namen, nicht aber unbedingt ihren unter der Adresse registriert. Ich setze dann meistens ihren auch noch dazu, aber dahinter, also:

```
O. und E. Mustermann-Schmidt
Strasse Nr
PLZ Ort
```

In der Anrede kannst du das dann auftrennen:

```
Sehr geehrte Frau Schmidt-Mustermann
Sehr geehrter Herr Mustermann
```

Comment: Danke für das Update. Die Abkürzung des Namens halte ich für nicht so gut. Entweder hinschreiben oder auslassen. Aber nicht abkürzen. Bei der Anschrift sollte der Name vollständig ausgeschrieben werden. Was machst du eigentlich, wenn beide Ehepartner einen Namen mit O. haben? Insgesamt stimme ich dir in den meisten Punkten nicht ganz zu, wobei wenn das für die Schweiz so halt gilt... Nun gut, ...

Comment: Per Gesetz keine Doppelnamen? Und was ist, wenn ich an Nicht-Schweizer schreibe?

Comment: @Em1 : Du überraschst mich jetzt ein wenig. Ich habe viel Post aus Österreich und Deutschland und versende auch viel umgekehrt. Ich habe noch nie einen Vornamen ausgeschrieben gesehen. Und wenn sie halt Otto und Ottilia heissen, dann steht dort O. und O. bzw. O. + O. - das habe ich auch schon gesehen. Man darf's ja halten, wie man will, aber ich bin sehr überrascht davon, dass du Namen ausschreiben willst :)

Comment: @Robert : Das Gesetz hat eigentlich keinen Einfluss auf meine Antwort, sondern war lediglich einführend erwähnt hinsichtlich des Problems, dass man beide Namen erwähnen müsste. Auch wenn's anders wäre: Ich würde die Briefe genauso anschreiben, wie in meiner Antwort geschrieben :)

Comment: Ich hab's wiederum noch nie gesehen, dass der Name nicht ausgeschrieben wurde und käme auch nicht auf die Idee, das zu machen.